# How to read an XML file with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB to generate Java classes from XML schema. Now I want to read an XML file with these classes, but can't. I try this

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(STDMP.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    STDMP ts = (STDMP)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);
    System.out.println(ts.getEDocument().getSender().getName());
```

and get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:113)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeEnumLeafInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeEnumLeafInfoImpl.java:87)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createEnumLeafInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createEnumLeafInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:229)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.getTarget(SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.getTarget(RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:66)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.getTarget(RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:54)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.ref(SingleTypePropertyInfoImpl.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.ref(RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:70)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.ref(RuntimeAttributePropertyInfoImpl.java:54)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:214)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:335)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1174)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at net.sf.hibernate.examples.quickstart.hib_main.main(hib_main.java:83)
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

I tried to get CoordSystem Name with code and classes generated by Dangling Piyush.

Code

```
        File xml_gkuzu = new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/XML/GKUZU_53ce0a8e-13e1-4e4e-99d9-2f45ae786d33!chz.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CoordSystem.class);
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/v2/STD_MP.xsd")));
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
CoordSystem cs = (CoordSystem)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);
System.out.println(cs.getName());
```

But get an exception in line `CoordSystem cs = (CoordSystem)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);`

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"STD_MP"). Expected elements are <{}Coord_System>
```

Comment: What xml are you trying to read?

Comment: This http://depositfiles.com/files/i0nnx3rng . And this is xml schema  https://portal.rosreestr.ru/wps/PA_FCCLPGUMWPSPtalApp/ru.fccland.pgu.infoblock?ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.handler.BeanNameParameterHandlerMapping-PATH=%2FFileDownloaderController&ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceServlet.directRequest=x&param_infoblock_name=cc_ib_555&param_infoblock_file_path=images/V02_STD_GKZU.zip

Comment: Can you post your xsd and xml.

Comment: The link is getting failed for schema.

Comment: Maybe i do something wrong when generate java classes? I use this command `xjc -d src -p gen STD_MP.xsd`

Comment: Sorry. This xsd http://depositfiles.com/files/xe650me7u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest do

```
 jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schemaLocation);
```

By doing this you can check whether your xml is validating against xsd or not and you can also find out where is the problem in xml by reading the stacktrace of SAXException or JAXBException.

UPDATE:

This is the link for generated java classses

[Generated Java Classes](http://depositfiles.com/files/i507r5nfp)

And follwing is the unmarshalling code for xml with validation against xsd.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.piyush.STDMP;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws JAXBException 
     * @throws SAXException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(STDMP.class);
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("C:/Users/CDAC/workspace/Testing/src/STD_MP.xsd")));
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        STDMP ts = (STDMP)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("E:/Testing.xml"));

        System.out.println(ts.getCoordSystems());
        System.out.println(ts.getEDocument());

    }

     }
```

Please change the xsd and xml location according to your machine.

Comment: But i get exeption in line  `JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(STDMP.class);` This is RootElement of schema.

Comment: Please send the schema i will try.

Comment: I add schema to last comment to question. This xsd depositfiles.com/files/xe650me7u

Comment: It is not allowing me to download right now so i'll come back to you in sometime...:)

Comment: I will waiting for you. Its will be nice if u generate a working java classes. ^__^

Comment: i have generated java classes and it is working perfectly and also validating the xml file against schema.

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete solution...Cheeers..:)

Comment: Hi:) Thank you for Classes and code. ) I test it and get a question: How to get CoordSystem Name for example? Please look at my last update.

Comment: JAXB kidding me. Its generate only templates of classes. If i want to get something from XML document i gonna add methods in this classes. Hand work its bad "____". But anyway thank you Piyush for your help. I think i love you. :)

Comment: **Answer to the next problem:**

Hey you are having the whole object of STDMP you can always get the parts of it by calling getter method on them....and jaxb provides you everything you just need to search little harder...:)

Comment: Yeah. Im dummy. I did not notice that some methods return a lists but i thought that they return one element and try to rewrite classes. No every think works fine. But Piyush how you generate this classes? I did not compare them but they bigger that mine. Can you tall me that?

Answer (score 2):

If you generate your JAXB model from an XML schema then you should generate the `JAXBContext` on the package name instead of a class.

You should do:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo");
```

And not:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(com.example.foo.Bar.class);
```

**Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: I bet this is right. You can also try if you prefer: JAXBContext.newInstance(com.example.foo.Bar.class.getPackage().getName());  , which I like because it helps if you need to refactor / move packages around.