# read Xml file with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to read a xml file (like below) but I get an Execption.
    Could you please help me how can I fix this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
"file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mojalal/Desktop/FirstXSD.xml">
<log>
    <property key="firstKey" value="firstValue"></property>
    <property key="secoundKey" value="secoundKey"></property>
    <property key="thirdKey" value="thirdValue"></property>  
</log>

<env>
    <property key="firstenv" value="fo"></property>
    <property key="123" value="333"></property> 
</env>
</config>
```

and this is my code that I want to read xml file:

```
    public class ReadXMLFilewithJAXB {
private static List<Property> customer;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {

 try {

    File file = new File("c:\\FirstXML.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Log.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    customer = (List<Property>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
 } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

}

Finally this is the Exception that I get:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"config"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:631)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1038)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:142)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:151)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:169)
    at firstExample.ReadXMLFilewithJAXB.main(ReadXMLFilewithJAXB.java:21)
```

Env POJO Class:

```
public class Env {
    List<Property> properties2;


    public Env() {
    }


    public Env(List<Property> properties2) {
        super();
        this.properties2 = properties2;
    }


    public List<Property> getProperties2() {
        return properties2;
    }

    public void setProperties2(List<Property> properties2) {
        this.properties2 = properties2;
    }
```

LOg POJO Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Log {
    List<Property> properties=new ArrayList<Property>();;

    public Log(){

    }

    public List<Property> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<Property> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
```

Comment: Which information are you trying to get from the XML document?  Are you only interested in the properties under the `log` element?

Comment: i want to get 2 seperate List from my XML file .

Comment: it means that get List1 for all of "key" and "value" that are in <log> tag and then get List2 for all "key" and "value" that are in <env> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an XML file with JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053379/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"config"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:631)
```

You need to ensure that you associate a class with the root element of the XML document using `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).  Alternatively you can use one of the unmarshal methods that take a `Class` parameter to tell JAXB what type of object you are unmarshalling.

---

**Domain Model (Config)**

I would recommend having a domain class like the following from which you could obtain the two lists of `Property` objects.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Config {

    private List<Property> logProperties = new ArrayList<Property>();
    private List<Property> envProperties = new ArrayList<Property>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="log")
    @XmlElement(name="property")
    public List<Property> getLogProperties() {
        return logProperties;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="env")
    @XmlElement(name="property")
    public List<Property> getEnvProperties() {
        return envProperties;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum17059227/input.xml");
        Config config = (Config) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mojalal/Desktop/FirstXSD.xml");
        marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mojalal/Desktop/FirstXSD.xml">
    <env>
        <property key="firstenv" value="fo"/>
        <property key="123" value="333"/>
    </env>
    <log>
        <property key="firstKey" value="firstValue"/>
        <property key="secoundKey" value="secoundKey"/>
        <property key="thirdKey" value="thirdValue"/>
    </log>
</config>
```

Comment: Where is `FirstXSD.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

When you describing an XML model, you need to begin with a root entity (in your case it's the`<config>` element).

```
@XmlRootElement(name="config")
class Config implements Serializable {
   private Log log;
   private Env env;

   @XmlElement(name="log")
   public Log getLog() {
      return this.log;
   }

   @XmlElement(name="env")
   public Env getEnv() {
      return this.env;
   }

   // Setters are omitted
}
```

And then you parse the XML like the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Config config = (Config) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
if (config != null && config.getLog() != null) {
   customer = config.getLog().getProperties();
}
```

Comment: i want to get 2 seperate List from my XML file  
it means that get List1 for all of "key" and "value" that are in <log> tag and then get List2 for all "key" and "value" that are in <env> tag.

Comment: Dear "mikhail" .. unfortunately                                customer = config.getLog().getProperties().size();
return "0" . whay?

Comment: Well, I can't tell you without seeing your implementation of Log and Env entities. Could you please post them?

Comment: i add Log and Env POJO Class to your Code

Comment: JAXB uses annotations to bind the data model (which are your entities) to the XML file being parsed. You are missing the annotations in your POJOs, so JAXB simply doesn't know about the properties it is supposed to fill. Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/ZH4c1eGM) to the working example.

Comment: For this use case you could use `@XmlElementWrapper` to eliminate the need to the `Log` and `Env` classes (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17066435/383861).