# Reading an XML file with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I can currently read the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="100" r="q">
<datas>
    <data>
        <age>29</age>
        <name>mky</name>
    </data>
</datas>
</customer>
```

Using the Customer class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

String name;
String age;
String id;
String r;

@XmlAttribute
public void setR(String R) {
    this.r = R;
}   

    /etc
}
```

I decided to extend the XML file to support multiple customers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customers>
<customer id="100" r="q">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>mky</name>
</customer>
<customer id="101" r="q">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>mky</name>
</customer>
</customers>
```

I then ran into some trouble trying to read this.

I tried adding a Customers class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customers{
private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    return customers;
}

@XmlElement
public void setCustomers(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
    this.customers = customers;
}

}
```

And then trying to print this with:

```
     try {

            File file = new File("/Users/s.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customers c = (Customers) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            System.out.println(c.getCustomers());

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }}
```

But I'm getting a null value for trying to print this. Can someone enlighten me on how I can read the second XML file?

Comment: Try changing the type of the `customers` property from `ArrayList<Customer>` to `List<Customer>`. (Haven't tried it, but at least every example I read uses `List` and if I generate code from an xsd file it uses `List` too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an XML file with JAXB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053379/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Customers` class to

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customers")
class Customers {
    private List<Customer> customers;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "customer")
    public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
}
```

What you don't want is a mismatch between the get/set methods for the XML element. If one is returning `ArrayList`, the other should accept an `ArrayList` argument. Similarly for `List` (which is just good practice).

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems using annotations, it is possible to remove them and use an instance of `JAXBElement` instead.
To do so:

1. **First** delete any annotation in your `Customers` class

   ```
   public class Customers{
     private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

     public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
       return customers;
     }

     public void setCustomers(ArrayList<Customer> customers) {
       this.customers = customers;
     }

   }
   ```
2. **Second** use an instance of `JAXBElement` in your parsing method

   ```
   try {

       File file = new File("/Users/s.xml");
       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);
       Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
       JAXBElement<Customers> je1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(file, Customers.class);
       Customers c = je1.getValue();
       System.out.println(c.getCustomers());

     } catch (JAXBException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

**However note that annotations are required when you want to override default behavior.**
You find a full example [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).